# How to toggle queued effects with multiple targets in jquery 1.9?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, fade, jquery-1.9

I have create a function to animate one div then fade another on click. 
When I click again the animation is to run in reverse.
The function works but the animate part jumps to its designated point without animating and only when run in reverse.

I believe the left margin is being set prior to the fade and so jumps to the set point after the fade completes but I do not know how to fix this.

**MY QUESTION**

How to run a fade followed by an animate with two different targets on click of a button. Then on toggle click to run in reverse. jquery 1.9

```
var toggle = false;
$('#btn1, #btn2').click(function(){
    $('#CtrCol').animate({marginLeft: toggle ? 251 : 0},{complete: function(){
        $('#LftCol').fadeToggle();
    }}); 
    toggle = ! toggle;
});
```

**MY SOLUTION**

```
var flag = 0;
$('#btn1, #btn2').click(function() {
    if (flag == 0) {
        $('#LftCol').fadeOut({complete: function(){
            $('#CtrCol').animate({marginLeft: 0});
        }});
        flag = 1
    }
    else if (flag == 1) {
        $('#CtrCol').animate({marginLeft: 251},{complete: function(){
            $('#LftCol').fadeIn();
        }});
        flag = 0
    }
});
```

Comment: You got the idea ! Maybe there's a more fancy way, but that should work fine. If you have any trouble, with multiple animation trigger, move the flag assignment in the callback. And use .stop().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set a flag to know in which direction to run the animation and check it in the .click function

```
if (flag == "right") // run right anim
  flag = "left"
else // run left anim
  flag = "right"
```

Edit: Keep the callback

Comment: Well I don't really know how you want to do your animation. Just use the if in the click function, and set the according flag in the callback.